# spaCy matcher in custom pipeline not matching any text

Tags: python, spacy

I'm new to spaCy and learning how to use the Matcher to extract the DOB from Wiki pages of actors, for example:

> Scarlett Ingrid Johansson (/dʒoʊˈhænsən/;[1] born November 22, 1984) is an American actress. The world's highest-paid actress in 2018 and 2019, she has featured multiple times on the Forbes Celebrity 100 list.

For my 'simple' solution, I'm trying to match against `born November 22, 1984`, extract the date, then tag it as "DOB".

My code works when running it directly against the `doc` object, but if I put it within the pipeline, it's not matching anything. What am I doing wrong?

My pattern:

```py
nlp = spacy.load("en_core_web_sm")

# pattern for `born MM DD, YYYY`
born_pattern = [{'LOWER': 'born'},
        {'ENT_TYPE': 'DATE'},
        {'ENT_TYPE': 'DATE'},
        {'ORTH': ','},
        {'ENT_TYPE': 'DATE'}]

matcher = Matcher(nlp.vocab)
matcher.add("DOB", [ born_pattern ])
```

When i test it like this, i get the output i want:

```py
testdoc = nlp("Alex, born January 22, 1960, is an athlete.")
matches = matcher(testdoc)
for match_id, start, end in matches:
  # grab the date
  print( testdoc[start+1:end])
```

The output: January 22, 1960

---

But when i run it through the pipeline, it doesn't match anything:

```py
@Language.component("dob_component")
def dob_component_function(doc):
    # Create an entity Span with the label "DOB" for all matches
    matches = matcher(doc)
    print("Matches found: ", len(matches))

    # the `start+1` will skip the "born" token
    doc.ents = list(doc.ents) + [Span(doc, start+1, end, label="DOB") for match_id, start, end in matches]
    return doc

nlp.add_pipe("dob_component", before="ner")
nlp.pipe_names

# output
# ['tok2vec',
# 'tagger',
# 'parser',
# 'attribute_ruler',
# 'lemmatizer',
# 'dob_component',
# 'ner']

testdoc = nlp("Alex, born January 22, 1960, is an athlete.")

#output
# Matches found:  0
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok so taking a break does help, and I'm lucky to stumble on this [article](https://medium.com/aiguys/mining-financial-stock-news-using-spacy-matcher-edfadbd17f32).

My issue was I was matching against entity type `DATE`, which doesn't exist yet because my custom function is running BEFORE the `ner` pipe. So my solution was to change the pattern to match against POS instead.